# Mercurial ( Tortoise hg ) clone creates subdirectory on clone command from within Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, mercurial, cicd

I updated a pretty old Jenkins environment including the Jenkins version and plugins due to security issues. ( windows server 12) We use mercurial for version control and Tortoise HG to use it.
Before the update, the

```
hg clone ${repository} .
```

command worked as expected. I cloned a local repository into an empty local Jenkins workspace directory. `repository` is the path to a local repository.

After the update, the clone command creates a subdirectory like

```
/a4kg98umnn6tgzh7ca52f63258c16afe7ehuj7jutgrd4mk889olphbgtrgtkl00a/
```

The Jenkins script is unchanged. The subdirectory name is always the same.
When I execute the clone within the cmd by hand, the output is the expected one ( without the subdirectory created ).

Is there any condition I have to keep in mind when I clone a repo within Jenkins via tortoishg.exe?